# Projections, show that subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ exist

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\phi:V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $\phi \circ \phi=\phi$. Show that there exist subspaces $V_1, V_2 \subseteq V$ such that $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ and that if $\alpha \in V$ can be written as $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, where $\alpha_1 \in V_1, \alpha_2 \in V_2$, then $\phi(\alpha)=\alpha_1$.

In general, I am aware that this is about a projection. I also know that if we take the projection matrix $P$, then $P^2=P$ which ties in with $\phi \circ \phi=\phi$. Also, projecting only leaves the component of the vector which is in the plane we project onto, which is the equivalent of $\phi(\alpha)=\alpha_1$. Having said that, I can't find a way to express this formally to show the existence of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are kernel and image of this transformation.

Comment: As part of the desired statement is "... and $\phi(\alpha)=\alpha_1$", it is clear what $V_1$ has to be (as well as from $\phi(\alpha_2)=0$ it is clear what $V_2$ has to be).

Comment: By linearity, $\phi(\alpha_1) + \phi(\alpha_2) = \alpha_1$, and applying $\phi$ to both sides, again using linearity, and using the identity $\phi^2 = \phi$ gives $\phi(\alpha_2) = 0$, so $V_2 \subseteq \ker \phi$. Similar manipulations give the results that @XuqiangQIN mentions, namely that that containment is an equality, and that $V_1 = \phi(V)$.

Comment: I'm sure that an answer to this question exists on this site, but I'm having a hard time finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat trick for the problem: note that
$$
\alpha = [\phi(\alpha)] + [\alpha - \phi(\alpha)]
$$
Thus, we have reached the desired conclusion with $V_1 = im(\phi)$ and $V_2 = im(id_V - \phi)$.